# dataframe columns to multtindex dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, multi-index

I have the following data in an Excel sheet and I want to read it as a multiindex dataframe:

```
    Y1     Y1      Y2           Y2
B   H1     H2      H1           H2
1   80     72      79.2         84.744
2   240    216     237.6        254.232
3   40     36      39.6         42.372
4   160    144     158.4        169.488
5   240    216     237.6        254.232
6   0      0       0            0
```

I am reading it as:

```
DATA = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx',sheet_name=None)
```

since I am reading other sheets too.

**Question 1:**

This data is not read as multi-index data. How do I make it read it as multi-index? Or maybe I should read it as a dataframe and then convert it to multi-index? 
Current result of reading as dataframe

```
DATA['Load']
      Y1 Y1.1     Y2     Y2.1
bus   H1   H2     H1       H2
1     80   72   79.2   84.744
2    240  216  237.6  254.232
3     40   36   39.6   42.372
4    160  144  158.4  169.488
5    240  216  237.6  254.232
6      0    0      0        0
```

**Question 2 and probably the more fundamental question:**

How do I deal with multi-indexing when one or more of the indexes are on the columns side? In this example, I want to access the data by specifying `B, Y, H`. I know how to work with multi-index when they are all as index, but can't get the hang of it when the indexes are on the columns.

Thank you very much for your help :)

PS:

Another sheet may look like the following:

```
from    to  x     ratea
1       2   0.4   10
1       4   0.6   80
1       5   0.2   10
2       3   0.2   10
2       4   0.4   10
2       6   0.3   10
3       5   0.2   10
4       6   0.3   10
```

where I will set `from` and `to` as set (`set_index(['from','to']`) to get a multi-index dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to read a dataframe like this to a multiindex users the header param in `pd.read_excel()`

```
df = pd.read_excel('myFile.xlsx', header=[0,1])

    Y1      Y2
B   H1  H2  H1  H2
1   80  72  79.2    84.744
2   240 216 237.6   254.232
3   40  36  39.6    42.372
4   160 144 158.4   169.488
5   240 216 237.6   254.232
6   0   0   0.0 0.000
```

this means that you are telling pandas that you have two header rows 0 and 1

after our conversation:

```
df = pd.read_excel('Book2.xlsx', header=[0,1])
df2 = df.unstack().to_frame()
idx = df2.swaplevel(0,2).swaplevel(1,2).index.set_names(['B', 'Y', 'H'])
df2.set_index(idx, inplace=True)

            0
B   Y   H   
1   Y1  H1  80.000
2   Y1  H1  240.000
3   Y1  H1  40.000
4   Y1  H1  160.000
5   Y1  H1  240.000
6   Y1  H1  0.000
1   Y1  H2  72.000
2   Y1  H2  216.000
3   Y1  H2  36.000
4   Y1  H2  144.000
5   Y1  H2  216.000
6   Y1  H2  0.000
1   Y2  H1  79.200
2   Y2  H1  237.600
3   Y2  H1  39.600
4   Y2  H1  158.400
5   Y2  H1  237.600
6   Y2  H1  0.000
1   Y2  H2  84.744
2   Y2  H2  254.232
3   Y2  H2  42.372
4   Y2  H2  169.488
5   Y2  H2  254.232
6   Y2  H2  0.000
```

Comment: Thank you. This works when I am reading only one sheet. If I understand you correctly, I need to read that sheet separately and I cannot read it with other sheets and later set the index, am I right?
And assuming it is separately read as you said, when I write df.index I do NOT get those headers as index. I don't understand why.
Any idea for question 2?

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: @Ali I think I answered your second question in my updated answer. What do your other sheets look like?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. After the data is read (assuming one sheet at a time), how do I set the indexes? Currently, if I ask for `df.index` I get 1 to 6, and not those headers. The challenge for me is that Column B AND Y and H must be index, and not only Y and H.

Comment: @Ali just for clarification you want the whole sample dataframe to be the row index: all the columns?

Comment: I want to be able to access the data by specifying `B,Y,H`
Similar to another sheet that I posted where I could specify `'from','to'` and then I specify column `'x'` and I get the x value, I want to be able to specify `B,H,Y` and get the corresponding value. (Maybe I am not understanding a concept properly, sorry if I am confusing you.)

Comment: @Ali So you don not want 'B' to be the row index but a column index?

Comment: Or all of them be row indexes. Can I make all of them row index? I am thinking of it similar to the other sheet of Excel. That's why I am thinking if I can have them all as row index, my problem will be solved.
In other words, when I ask for index of that dataframe, I want to get `B` and `Y` and `H`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182900/discussion-between-chris-and-ali).